# Solving systems of ODEs using parametric solutions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find out if a generalisation of the methods found in this paper http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/788/1/012028/pdf have been developed to solve a system of ODEs only using parametric solutions?

For instance if there are a set of equations where $x_i(t)$ are some functions with $$ F(x_1,\ldots,x_n,t) =0
$$
and some $x_i'=G_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n,t)$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$

Is there a technique (for instance seperation of variables like) to resolve such problems? Thanks!

Edit: I've seen similar two the usual two coupled system here [Analytical solution to coupled nonlinear ODEs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834523/analytical-solution-to-coupled-nonlinear-odes), but really if there is a known generalisation for three or more odes that is what I wish to discuss!

I'll give an example

Take the three body system $a(t),b(t),c(t)$, where $f(t),g(t)$ are known functions and we solve for $a,b,c$ with
$$ a'(t) = f(t)c(t)$$ 
$$ b'(t) = g(t)c(t) $$
$$ c'(t) = \frac{1}{2}f(t) (1-2 a(t)) - g(t)b(t)$$

If one assumes the functions are non zero, then rearranging the first two we figure that the functions $a,b,c$ are constrained by

$$ c^2 + b(b-1) + a^2= \text{constant}$$

Which is an ellipsoidal constaint.